# Quiero eliminar un producto cuando el usuario tenga el role = 'Admin'

Tags: php, sql

Quiero insertar el valor *"eliminado"* en el campo **state** de la tabla **product** cuando el usuario con el **role = 'Admin'** ejecute la acción, o el usuario propietario de la publicación decida hacerlo.
He ejecutado un script para hacerlo pero no me esta funcionando y no se cual es la razón.

**Código:**

```
if(isset($_POST['delete-product'])){

    if($errors == ''){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE product SET product.state = '$delete' INNER JOIN users ON users.role = 'Admin' WHERE product.user_id = $usuario_iden AND product.id_producto = $post OR users.role = 'Admin'"
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':usuario_iden' => $usuario_iden,
            ':post' => $post
        ));

    }

}
```

*Espero que me puedan ayudar, un saludo.*

Comment: ¿A tu consulta no le falta usar marcadores de nombre o posición? es que veo que usas consultas preparadas pero no veo lo mencionado en tu update

Comment: Además de lo que menciona @BetaM, te sería más fácil tener almacenado el usuario logueado ya en algún lado de manera que puedas acceder a sus roles de manera rápida sin necesidad de hacer otra query cada vez que realiza una acción.

Comment: @BetaM Logre que elimine el producto actualizando el state, pero ahora el problema es que eliminado todos los productos que existen en la base de datos y esa no es la idea, solo debe de eliminar 1 `if($errors == ''){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE product INNER JOIN users ON users.role = 'Admin' SET product.state = '$delete' WHERE product.user_id = $usuario_iden AND product.id_producto = $post OR users.role = 'Admin'"
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':usuario_iden' => $usuario_iden,
            ':post' => $post
        ));

    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes un problema con tu sentencia sql, me explico:

1.- Normalmente haces un update de una tabla en base a un id (de producto en tu caso), por lo que no necesitas la relacion (JOIN).
2.- si entendi bien, la condicion es:

producto=$producto AND ((tipousuario="admin") OR (propietario=$usuarioactual))

Como regla general, yo nunca hago un UPDATE antes de verificar la informacion, es decir, primero valido si el usuario PUEDE hacerlo y despues hago el update en el supuesto de que cuente con autorizacion...

if ((tipousuario="admin") OR (propietario=$usuarioactual)) { UPDATE producto... }

espero que esto te ayude.

P.D. por cierto, tampoco pongo un boton de "borrar" si el usuario NO tiene los permisos necesarios, esto evitaria la validacion al hacer el update ya que solo llegaria ahi si existe el boton.